# Replace a string in every column in a specific table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB table that has many tables. I want to search each of these tables to find which has the string and then replace it with another.

What I want is if I find one field that has this string, then update it to another string

I've tried this really ugly query:

```
UPDATE `myTable` 

SET
c1 = 'hello',
c2 = 'hello',
c3 = 'hello',
c4 = 'hello',
c5 = 'hello',
c6 = 'hello'

WHERE 
c1 = 'hi',
c2 = 'hi',
c3 = 'hi',
c4 = 'hi',
c5 = 'hi',
c6 = 'hi'
```

But this is obvious wrong since if `c1` is `'hello'` then instead of just updating `c1` to `'hi'` it updates all fields to `'hi'`

Comment: I would just do a separate update for each column.

Answer (score 3):

You want conditional update:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET c1 = CASE WHEN c1='hi' THEN 'hello' else c1 end
   ,c2 = CASE WHEN c2='hi' THEN 'hello' else c2 end
   -- and so on...
WHERE 'hi' IN (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5);
```

Comment: is `where` necessary?

Comment: @vivek_23 Nope, but there is no case of updating rows that shouldn't change at all.

Comment: Whether you filter only rows that has a `hi` or you run checks on all rows regardless of whether it needs a change or not, I presume both would take approximately same number of operations.

Comment: @vivek_23 Let's assume that I have table with 100,000 rows. And there is only 10 rows that contain `hi`. I don't want to update `99,990` rows with `A->A`(identity update)  and generate all unnecessary log growth.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the fact that it would update same value with itself.